# Escape quotes in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to use a href onclick event in kendo grid template. When I click on the link I need the alert to diplay path text but it gives "PDF undefined error". I think it could be an issue with escape quotes.

${PDF} returns a string value.

```
template: "<a id='${PDF}' class='clsPDF' onclick='setpdf(\${PDF});' href='\\#'>View</a>"


 <script>

function setpdf(path)
{
  alert(path);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest slightly different approach. Instead of using inline function you can use a delegate function attached to your Grid element which will take care of all buttons like the one you defined in the template.

e.g.

```
$("#gridName").on("click", ".clsPDF" , function(){
    var model = $("#gridName").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
    alert('you clicked on item with id' + model.TheIdProperty);
})
```

I hope this gives you the idea. I think it is cleaner this way.

Answer (score 0):

When the browser looks at the link make sure it sees it like this:

```
<a id='someId' class='clsPDF' onclick='setpdf("pdf.pdf");' href='#'>View</a>
```

If it sees it like this:

```
<a id='someId' class='clsPDF' onclick='setpdf(pdf.pdf);' href='\\#'>View</a>
```

It will think pdf is a javascript object/variable and try and use it.

So you are right it is most likely a problem with quotes. You could try wrapping your \${PDF} with escaped double quotes:

\"\${PDF}\"